# Associação de várias classes em Java

Tags: java, classes

O projeto consiste em um sistema de gerenciamento para uma transportadora, onde um administrador gerencia viagens, e estas viagens possuem motoristas e caminhões.

Utilizei associação para relacionar as classes, porém estou tendo dificuldades para finalizar um método de verificação de disponibilidade de caminhões e motoristas.

Como faço para receber estas informações em um método da classe `Viagem`? Como posso "amarrar" os dados de `Motorista` e `Caminhao` dentro de uma viagem?

```
public class Administrador extends Funcionario{

    private static int codAdministrador=0;
    private String login;
    private String senha;
    int contViagem=0;
    private Viagem []viagem = new Viagem[contViagem];

    public Administrador(String nome, String cpf, String email, double salario, String endereco, String rg,
            int codAdministrador, String login, String senha, int contViagem) {
        super(nome, cpf, email, salario, endereco, rg);
        codAdministrador++;
        this.login = login;
        this.senha = senha;
        this.contViagem=contViagem;
    }   

    public int getCodAdministrador() {
        return codAdministrador;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }


    public Viagem planejarViagem(Viagem viagem, Caminhao veiculo, Motorista piloto){
        if(viagem.verificaStatus(veiculo, piloto) == true){
            return viagem;
        }
        return null;
    }

    /*public boolean verificaDisponibilidadeCaminhao(Caminhao veiculo){

        if(veiculo.getStatus() != true){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    }

    public boolean verificaDisponibilidadeMotorista(Motorista piloto){
        if(piloto instanceof Motorista){
            Motorista aux = (Motorista) piloto;
            if(aux.getStatus() != true)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        return false;       
    }*/

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder info = new StringBuilder();

        info.append("\nRelatório de Viagem")
            .append("\nNome do Gerente que emitiu o relatório: "+getNome())
            .append("\nDados da viagem"+viagem.toString());

        return info.toString();
    }

}

public class Motorista extends Funcionario{

    private int codMotorista;
    private boolean status;


    public Motorista(String nome, String cpf, String email, double salario, String endereco, String rg,
            int codMotorista, boolean status) {
        super(nome, cpf, email, salario, endereco, rg);
        this.codMotorista = codMotorista;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getCodMotorista() {
        return codMotorista;
    }

    public boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder info = new StringBuilder();

        info.append("\nCargo: Motorista")
            .append("\nCodigo do Motorista: "+codMotorista)
            .append("\nStatus: "+status);

        return info.toString();
    }



}


public class Caminhao {

    private String marca, modelo, placa;
    private int ano, contaManutencao = 0;
    private boolean status;
    private double quilometragemInicial;
    private double quilometragemFinal;  
    private Manutencao manutencaoPreventiva;

    public Caminhao(String marca, String modelo, String placa, int ano, boolean status, double quilometragemInicial, double quilometragemFinal) {
        super();
        this.marca = marca;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.placa = placa;
        this.ano = ano;
        this.status=status;
        this.quilometragemInicial = quilometragemInicial;
        this.quilometragemFinal = quilometragemFinal;

    }


    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }

    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public String getPlaca() {
        return placa;
    }

    public int getAno() {
        return ano;
    }

    public double getQuilometragemInicial() {
        return quilometragemInicial;
    }

    public double getQuilometragemFinal() {
        return quilometragemFinal;
    }

    public boolean getStatus() {
        return status;      
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {

        StringBuilder info = new StringBuilder();

        info.append("Dados do Caminhao: ")
            .append("\nMarca: "+marca)
            .append("\nModelo: "+modelo)
            .append("\nPlaca: "+placa)
            .append("\nAno: "+ano)
            .append("\nConta Manutencao: "+contaManutencao)
            .append("\nStatus Caminhao: "+status)
            .append("\nQuilometragem Inicial: "+quilometragemInicial)
            .append("\nQuilometragem Final: "+quilometragemFinal)
            .append("ManutencaoPreventiva: "+manutencaoPreventiva);
        return info.toString();
    }




}

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Viagem{

    private String horaSaida, horaChegada, dataChegada, dataSaida, destino, origem;
    private int codViagem;
    int indiceGeral=0;
    private Manutencao revisao;
    private Caminhao []veiculo = new Caminhao[20];
    private Motorista[]piloto = new Motorista[15];


    public Viagem(String horaSaida, String horaChegada, String dataChegada, String dataSaida, String destino,
            String origem, int codViagem) {
        super();
        this.horaSaida = horaSaida;
        this.horaChegada = horaChegada;
        this.dataChegada = dataChegada;
        this.dataSaida = dataSaida;
        this.destino = destino;
        this.origem = origem;
        this.codViagem = codViagem;
    }

    public String getHoraSaida() {
        return horaSaida;
    }

    public String getHoraChegada() {
        return horaChegada;
    }

    public String getDataChegada() {
        return dataChegada;
    }

    public String getDataSaida() {
        return dataSaida;
    }

    public String getDestino() {
        return destino;
    }

    public String getOrigem() {
        return origem;
    }

    public int getCodViagem() {
        return codViagem;
    }



    public boolean verificaStatus(Caminhao veiculo, Motorista piloto){

        Caminhao auxC = (Caminhao) veiculo;
        Motorista aux = (Motorista) piloto;

        if(auxC.getStatus() != true && aux.getStatus() != true){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    }

    public Viagem planejarViagem(Viagem []viagem, Caminhao []veiculo, Motorista []piloto){
        if(viagem[indiceGeral].verificaStatus(veiculo[indiceGeral], piloto[indiceGeral]) == true){
            indiceGeral++;
            return viagem[indiceGeral];
        }
        return null;
    }

    public double calculaKm(double kmInicial, double kmFinal){
        return kmFinal-kmInicial;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder info = new StringBuilder();

        info.append("Viagem \nHora Saida: "+horaSaida+" hrs")
            .append("\nHora Chegada: "+horaChegada+" hrs")
            .append("\nData Chegada: "+dataChegada)
            .append("\nData Saida: "+dataSaida)
            .append("\nDestino: "+destino)
            .append("\nOrigem: "+origem)
            .append("\nCodigo da Viagem "+codViagem)
            .append("\nViagens realizadas: "+indiceGeral)
            .append("\nRevisao: "+revisao)
            .append("\nDados do Veículo: "+veiculo.toString())
            .append("\nQuilometragem percorrida: "+calculaKm(kmInicial, kmFinal))
            .append("\n\nPiloto que realizou a viagem: "+piloto.toString());

        return info.toString();
    }





}
```

Comment: Uma viagem pode ter 20 caminhões e 15 motoristas? Pra que? O que é este `super()` no construtor? A viagem pode existir sem um caminhão e motoristas associados? Qual é a intenção do `verificaStstus()`? Existe alguma motivo para uso da *tag* [tag:array-associativo]? Você sabe do que se trata?

Comment: Uma viagem possui apenas um caminhão e um motorista, o super() é o padrão gerado automaticamente pelo Eclipse, e faz referência à classe Object. A viagem só pode existir se houverem motoristas e caminhões associados. E o metódo verificaStatus faz o controle de motoristas e caminhoes, caso eles estejam ocupados (viajando), não será possível efetuar a viagem.          Quanto à tag array-associativo, devo ter me enganado no momento de digitar as tags e acabei insrindo sem querer...

Comment: A viagem pode ser criado com caminhão e motorista ocupados, mas impedida dela se realizar, ou quando isto ocorre, a viagem nem pode ser criada?

Comment: Os atributos do tipo boolean, por padrão são iniciados como false, portanto, o método verificaStatus com seu if faz o seguinte: se o status de um caminhão ou motorista é false, ele não está ocupado, portanto, o método retorna true, dizendo que é possível realizar a viagem. Caso contrário, o retorno indica false, pois eles estão ocupados e a viagem é impedida de ser realizada...

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

Embora tenha coisas estranhas vou responder de acordo com o que está descrito na pergunta e nos comentários. Se os requisitos estiverem errados é claro que a solução sairá errada, mas aí o problema não é de programação. Talvez a dificuldade em codificar seja por ter requisitos ambíguos ou conflitantes.

Primeiro elimina-se o *array* de caminhão e motorista já que só pode ter um em cada viagem:

```
private Caminhao veiculo;
private Motorista piloto;
```

Arrumamos o construtor. Tiramos a chamada a `super()` que não faz o menor sentido (se o Eclipse faz isso, é um IDE muito ruim). E colocamos um parâmetro para preencher esses campos, afinal a viagem não pode existir sem esses dados. [Pra isso servem os construtores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

```
public Viagem(String horaSaida, String horaChegada, String dataChegada, String dataSaida, String destino, String origem, int codViagem, Caminhao, caminhao, Motorista, motorista) {
    this.horaSaida = horaSaida;
    this.horaChegada = horaChegada;
    this.dataChegada = dataChegada;
    this.dataSaida = dataSaida;
    this.destino = destino;
    this.origem = origem;
    this.codViagem = codViagem;
    this.caminhao = caminhao;
    this.piloto = motorista;
}
```

Um método pode ser muito simplificado:

```
public boolean verificaStatus(Caminhao veiculo, Motorista piloto) {
    return !veiculo.getStatus() && !piloto.getStatus();
}
```

Nem falei que provavelmente está [exagerando no uso de *getters* e *setters*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Travel.java).

Não consigo entender o método `planejarViagem()` colocado depois. Ele não parece fazer o menor sentido e está em desacordo com a descrição do problema. Talvez haja um erro generalizado no código e planejamento das classes, mas não tenho como afirmar sem conhecer o requisitos certos. Talvez esse método indique que os requisitos estejam errados. Mas só posso trabalhar com o que foi expressado.

Na verdade você precisa aprender mais como funcionam expressões booleanas. Ela é usada de forma redundante aí também.

Normalmente o `toString()` é para uso interno do código. Não digo que está errado, mas listar todas informações do objeto não costuma ser o mais certo. Quando precisa disso é melhor ter um método mais apropriado. Parece ser abuso do recurso.

Também seria bom manter um padrão de nomenclatura das coisas. Acho estranho ter lugares que o motorista passa ser chamado de piloto e o caminhão de veículo. Veículo me parece mais correto sempre a não ser que tenha algum lugar que precise das discriminação exata do tipo de veículo, o que não parece ser o caso, não há estrutura para isto.