# Métodos Getters e Setters

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, getters-setters

No meu curso, estou aprendendo *getters* que pega "dados" e *setters*, que insere/modifica.

Fiz meu código assim pra classe caneta:

```
<?php

class Caneta {
    public $modelo;
    private $ponta;

public function getModelo(){
    return $this->modelo;
}
public function setModelo($m){
    $this->modelo = $m;
}
public function getPonta(){
    return $this->ponta;
}
public function setPonta($p) {
    $this->ponta = $p;
}

}
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Aula 02 POO</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>
        <?php
            require_once 'Caneta.php';
            $c1 = new Caneta;
            $c1->setModelo("BIC");
            $c1->setPonta(0.5);
            print("Eu tenho uma caneta {$c1->getModelo()} com a ponta {$c1->getPonta()}");
        ?>
        </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

No caso aquelas palavrinhas ali, *set* e *get*, eu poderia trocar por qualquer outra? Por exemplo (somente dúvida), poderia fazer assim?

```
<?php

class Caneta {
    public $modelo;
    private $ponta;

public function puxarModelo(){
    return $this->modelo;
}
public function inserirModelo($m){
    $this->modelo = $m;
}
public function puxarPonta(){
    return $this->ponta;
}
public function inserirPonta($p) {
    $this->ponta = $p;
}

}
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Aula 02 POO</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>
        <?php
            require_once 'Caneta.php';
            $c1 = new Caneta;
            $c1->inserirModelo("BIC");
            $c1->inserirPonta(0.5);
            print("Eu tenho uma caneta {$c1->puxarModelo()} com a ponta {$c1->puxarPonta()}");
        ?>
        </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Estou aprendendo com *get* e *set*, mas queria saber se isso é padrão/obrigatório, ou, se eu posso mudar (se eu quiser) sem problemas?

Comment: Padrão é uma referência, caso alguém mexa no seu código saberá que o get e set fazem determinada ação. Mas você pode tranquilamente alterar para o que lhe convém.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não é obrigatório. De fato, em PHP, esse mecanismo quase sempre é um canhão pra matar passarinho nesses casos. Na maioria das situações, dada a natureza de *script* do PHP, há pouco ou zero ganho em usar esse tipo de coisa, a não ser que o método faça alguma coisa útil. Se a pessoa ficou com inveja de programar em Java usando o PHP, então passa para o Java. Ou pelo menos vá para Hack que são linguagens *enterprise*. Essa é uma técnica inadequada para *scripts*.

Na verdade eu prefiro o uso de propriedades [*getter/setter*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45285/101), sempre que possível, assim mantêm-se a sintaxe de atributo público adicionando comportamento ao acesso ao atributo: [Quando usar método mágico __contructor ou set e get?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45285/101).

Já há uma [comparação das duas formas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110785/101).

Veja [Deveríamos utilizar todas variáveis como privadas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/202227/101).

Sempre que for usar alguma coisa, deve-se perguntar qual a vantagem de adotar aquele *design*. Se não souber responder ou se não souber porque naquele contexto, simplesmente não use. Se não puder dizer quais as desvantagens, também estará correndo risco de usar algo que causará problema no futuro. Usar porque todo mundo está fazendo não é uma boa ideia. Já havia a expressão "se todo mundo está jogando em um abismo, você se joga também?".

Se usar onde não precisa ou não souber porque está usando complicará a vida do programador no futuro.

Algumas pessoas até dizem que nunca deveria fazer dessa forma. Então para estas pessoas não usar as palavras `get` e `set` pode ser uma boa. Dizem que você só deve criar métodos que façam alguma coisa útil e que este par de métodos apenas encapsulando um atributo não deve ser criado nunca.

Note que essas pessoas não pregam o uso de campos públicos, apenas que todos métodos devem ter função específica. Em geral isso costuma ser exagero e pode dificultar certos padrões.

O que eu estou dizendo é: **em *script*** o uso de campos públicos não é tão complicado assim, principalmente se tiver interesse em usar os métodos mágicos que quase nenhum programador PHP conhece, apesar de ser um método mais adequado. Talvez por ele não ter sido bem implementado na linguagem, talvez porque desconhecem o recurso, talvez porque gostam do estilo do Java.

Tem várias perguntas sobre o assunto e pode mostrar como usar, mesmo em PHP, do jeito mais *enterprise*:

- [Quando usar Setters e Getters?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43757/101)
- [Por que não devo alterar os "getter"s e "setter"s?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/134750/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre referenciar um atributo diretamente ou por get/set?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129353/101)
- [O que acontece na vida real em um ambiente de desenvolvedores se o programador não encapsular um atributo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/204355/101)
- [Propriedade Vs variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101)
- [Getters e setters são uma ilusão do encapsulamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25995/101)
- [Por que é uma má prática ter atributos int?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/132272/101)
- [Getters e Setters só podem "andar" juntos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44739/101)
- [Exemplo real do uso de encapsulamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/293801/101)
- [O que acontece na vida real em um ambiente de desenvolvedores se o programador não encapsular um atributo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/204355/101)
- [Em estruturas (struct) é necessário o uso de getters e setters ou apenas em classes (class)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262764/101)
- [Campo público X propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324099/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre referenciar um atributo diretamente ou por get/set?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129353/101)
- [Como construir uma classe corretamente com métodos de acesso?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/237154/101)
- [Propriedade Vs variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101)
- [Como transformar os atributos em propriedades?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/149348/101)
- [Como usar a 9º regra de Object Calisthenics no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220497/101)
- [Qual a relação entre encapsulamento e polimorfismo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214767/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

Os métodos `getters` e `setters` são métodos para **acessar** e **modificar** informações de classes que possuem encapsulamento. Você pode colocar o nome que quiser na função, mas isso já é um padrão estabelecido, se você fugir a regra, estará complicando a vida do futuro programador que venha dar manutenção em seu código.