# Em estruturas (struct) é necessário o uso de getters e setters ou apenas em classes (class)?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes, struct, getters-setters

É necessário utilizar *setters* e *getters* em estruturas para manter as boas praticas ou é necessário apenas em classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não é necessário em nenhuma das duas. E esse negócio de boas práticas é uma falácia.

Por exemplo, em C++ não é comum usar esse tipo de mecanismo. Tem quem use, mas em tipos de aplicações específicas e que geralmente ficaria melhor em outra linguagem.

Tem lugar para fazer isso, mas os programadores C++ costumam estar acima da média e sabem que em muitos casos não é necessário. Eles não seguem boas práticas, eles entendem tudo como funciona, e sabem os requisitos de forma adequada, e não seguem receita de bolo. Toda vez que você faz algo porque é boa prática, já está fazendo errado, mesmo que funcione. Se fizer porque entende correta e completamente que aquilo é necessário naquele contexto, aí tem boa chance de ser o certo.

Uma estrutura e uma classe essencialmente é a mesma coisa no C++, você pode até usar de forma diferente, mas tecnicamente não há diferença a não ser o padrão de visibilidade dos membros.

C++ é uma linguagem mais dogmática, ela permite você fazer tudo, mas espera que você só use o que realmente é necessário.

Eu costumo dizer, se não entender todas implicações de usar um mecanismo, não o use. O site está cheio de informações sobre o assunto em diversas linguagens. Funciona igual em todas, a diferença é só cultural e frequência que ele é necessário.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Não sei se está certo ou errado, mas minha duvida só aumentou quando vi o -1 ali no lado, existe alguma fonte de que não é necessário uso de getters e setters? Pois pelo que aprendi na faculdade e em videos do youtube o correto é fazer o uso de getters e setters não apenas por boas praticas, mas sim porque é necessário para uma maior segurança.

Comment: A fonte soy yo :D Você não terá a resposta que deseja. Bom, na verdade terá, cada um dará a sua e você não saberá em quem confiar, por isso que eu disse que tem que aprender tudo para tomar suas próprias decisões com fundamento e confiança e não depender de outras pessoas, até porque na hora de fazer é você que terá que decidir e terá que saber, não tem como escapar, tem que aprender, não adianta seguir receita de bolo.

Comment: Não exite algo universal que diz o que é certo, e minha resposta diz isto. Você viu isto em C++ ou outra linguagem? A fonte que viu é confiável? é alguém que trabalha há mais de 30 anos com isto e mexeu em vários tipos de softwares, com variados requisitos e investigou sobre a vantagem de usar cada coisa? Ou a fonte é alguém que aprendeu em um livro, blog, YT, ou até na faculdade e ficou repetindo sem entender porque estava fazendo aquilo? Eu sei porque eu faço e porque não faço. Por isso não falo para os outros sempre fazer ou nunca fazer. Quem fala isto está fundamentalmente errado.

Comment: Tudo bem, acredito que essa talvez vai ser a melhor resposta que vou ter, só uma coisa que aconteceu recentemente comigo, eu tinha feito uma classe que armazenava pontos(Para desenho em D3D9) e eu tinha colocado os valores x e y como public na classe, e por algo que eu não sei explicar, meus valores estava mudando sozinho para outros valores, eu tenho a absoluta certeza que não tinha nenhuma linha de código trocando os valores delas, então eu andei pesquisando e conheci os getters e setters e adicionei os métodos getters e setters e troquei para private e resolveu o problema.

Comment: Não tenho como ajudar sem ver em detalhes. Essas coisas de baixo nível ninguém encapsula nada. Se você falar em *getter/setter* neguinho te bate :) É diferente quando faz sentido ter um método que faça algo. Outra coisa. funcionar é diferente de estar correto, o pior que pode te acontecer é algo funcionar. Nada garante que funcionará sempre. Se estiver certo funcionará sempre.

Answer (score 1):

A utilização de *getters* e *setters* não é necessária nem obrigatória em nenhum dos dois casos, mas como você citou são boas práticas que ajudam tanto em questão de encapsulamento, quanto em facilitar a adequação do valor recebido à variável na qual ele será armazenado, por exemplo, realizando cálculos ou garantindo que uma *string* recebida terá apenas dois dígitos.

Comment: Isso não tem nada a ver com segurança. Tem a ver com abstração e encapsulamento.

Comment: Resposta editada, obrigado pelo retorno Pablo Almeida

Answer (score 1):

Não é necessário em nenhuma das duas, mas, por padrão, em `struct`s, os atributos são públicos. Isso significa que, se você tem uma `class` e quer acessar um dos atributos de um dos exemplares dela pelo lado de fora, precisa definir o atributo como `public` ou criar o acessador e modificador ("getter" e "setter") pra ele.