# Acessar atributos privados de uma classe dentro de outra classe

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, php-7, private

Comecei a estudar PHPOO e estou com dificuldades pra acessar os atributos da classe `Pessoa` que são privados dentro da classe `Login`, segue o código

#### class Pessoa

```
class Pessoa {
    private $nome;
    private $idade;

    public function getNome(){
        return $this->nome;
    }

    public function setNome($n){
        $this->nome = $n;
    }

    public function getIdade(){
        return $this->idade;
    }

    public function setIdade($i){
        $this->idade = $i;
    }

    public function dados_nome() {
        $this->nome = "Fulano de Tal";
        $this->setNome($this->nome);
        //echo ''.$this->nome.' '.$this->sobrenome.' de '.$this->idade.' está online.';
    }

    public function dados_idade() {
        $this->idade = 21;
        $this->setIdade($this->idade);
    }
}
```

#### class Login

```
class Login {
    public $email;
    public $pass;

    public function logar() {
        $this->email = "teste@teste.com";
        $this->pass = "123456";

        if ($this->email == "teste@teste.com" and $this->pass == "123456") :
            $dados = new Pessoa;
            $dados->dados_nome();
            $dados->dados_idade();
            echo "Bem vindo ".$dados->nome." de ".$dados->idade." anos.";
        else :
            echo "Dados incorretos.";
        endif;
    }
}
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property Pessoa::$nome in C:\xampp\htdocs\testes\class.php:47 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\testes\index.php(12): Login->logar() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\testes\class.php on line 47

Comment: As propriedades privadas só podem ser acessadas pela própria classe. Não dá para você instanciar a classe `Pessoa` e querer acessar, diretamente, a propriedade `$nome` sendo que ela é privada, caso você queira atingir este objeto você tem duas opções: Alterar a visualidade para `public` ou acessar o método `getNome()`. [Documentação](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: @ValdeirPsr ué, eu achava que os `getters` e `setters` era pra isso, pra acessar um atributo privado fora ou dentro de outra classe

Comment: eles são, mas você está tentando acessar um objeto privado de forma direta. `echo "Bem vindo ".$dados->nome."` e, como a propriedade é privada, não é possível. Você deve utilizar `echo "Bem vindo ".$dados->getNome()."`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declarando o atributo como private não se pode acessá-la diretamente de outra classe. Você apenas conseguirá acessar esse atributo indiretamente através de um método. No exemplo exposto, para conseguir ter acesso aos atributos nome e idade, deve-se instanciar a classe Pessoa como exemplo abaixo:

```
Pessoa $p = new Pessoa();
$p.getNome(); // acessa-se indiretamente o atributo nome
$p.getIdade(); // acessa-se indiretamente o atributo idade
```

Answer (score 7):

O objetivo de ser privado é justamente não poder acessar (ajuda no encapsulamento), então ainda bem que está com dificuldade. Um dos objetivos de orientação a objeto é esconder os detalhes de implementação e uma das formas de fazer isso é deixar membros privados, se você tentar acessar o que é privado, ou está querendo fazer algo que não pode ou o membro não deveria ser privado, aí você tem que decidir como arrumar.

Eu nem vou tentar afirmar o que é o certo porque quase todo código OOP que vejo, especialmente em PHP, está errado, então a solução é fazer tudo de novo ou deixar de fazer OOP, afinal quase ninguém faz certo, e aí tem os malefícios de usar esta técnica e não ganha os benefícios que poderia trazer se fizesse certo, o que inclusive a maioria das pessoas não consegue dizer que benefícios reais ela teve por fazer daquela forma.

Mas neste caso parece apenas que deveria ter usado o método *getter* de nome e idade em vez de acessar o campo. Inclusive porque no comentário parece achar que está chamando os métodos e não está.

[Um dos erros que as pessoas cometem é chamar de atributo o que na verdade é um campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

[Outro erro comum é abusar de *getters* e *setters*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101), OOP de verdade os abomina. A impressão que dá é que nem queria usá-los mesmo, mas fez porque viu em algum lugar alguém fazendo isso. A classe tem métodos um pouco melhores, apesar de nomes bem ruins e que também não faz nada muito útil e talvez até errado.

Mas o erro mais grave é a estruturação incorreta de classes e criar coisas que não fazem sentido e não ajudam o código ficar melhor.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).