# Passagem de objeto como parâmetro altera o objeto original

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Estou a passar um objeto como parâmetro para uma outra função. Em meus anos de estudo na faculdade sempre foi diferenciado a passagem por referência e valor, no caso do objeto ele sempre trabalha como passagem por referência?

Segue as situações

Essa é minha model utilizada para realizar os testes

```
class Teste
{
    private $atributo;

    public function getAtributo(){
        return $this->atributo;
    }

    public function  setAtributo($atributo){
        $this->atributo = $atributo;
    }

    public function incrementar($teste){
        $teste->atributo += 1;
    }
}
```

#### SITUAÇÃO 1

Na primeira situação eu fiz uma instância do objeto `Teste`, inicializei o atributo como zero e enviei ele a função incrementar

```
    $teste = new Teste();
    $teste->atributo = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
        $teste->incrementar($teste);
    }
```

obtendo o seguinte resultado

```
$i = 0 => $teste->atributo = 1
$i = 1 => $teste->atributo = 2
$i = 2 => $teste->atributo = 3
```

#### SITUAÇÃO 2

Na segunda situação eu fiz a inicialização do atributo com 0 e enviei a própria *model* como parâmetro

```
    $this->atributo = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
        $teste->incrementar($this);
    }
```

e obtive o seguinte resultado

```
$i = 0 => $teste->atributo = 1
$i = 1 => $teste->atributo = 2
$i = 2 => $teste->atributo = 3
```

#### SITUAÇÃO 3

Na terceira situação eu inicializei o atributo com 0 e enviei um clone da Model como parâmetro

```
    $this->atributo = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
        $teste->incrementar(clone $this);
    }
```

e obtive o seguinte resultado

```
$i = 0 => $teste->atributo = 0
$i = 1 => $teste->atributo = 0
$i = 2 => $teste->atributo = 0
```

Agora a questão é: Isso seria um comportamento padrão da orientação a objetos? Existe uma maneira correta de fazer o envio desses objetos sem alterar os atributos do objeto original?

> Os métodos no exemplo acima estão na mesma classe para facilitar pra mim a exemplificação. Na ocorrência real as chamadas são em classes diferentes e ocorre o mesmo comportamento.

Comment: Seria-lhe algum problema se eu trocar o nome da classe e das instância na explicação?

Comment: Não, não seria @AugustoVasques

Comment: Algum motivo para fazer isto? Esta classe não faz o menor sentido, como ela é conceitualmente errada, nada importa. Conforme sua resposta eu posso tentar responder a pergunta, inclusive porque eu tenho uma "opinião" diferente da resposta já postada. Poderia colocar o código todo usado para testar?

Comment: O motivo seria apenas para entendimento do processo, apenas. A classe criei apenas para exemplificar a situação, para entendimento (desculpas a todos pelos nomes usados). Deveria ter criado 2 classes para exemplificar melhor o real ocorrido, vou tentar fazer expor melhor a dúvida.

Comment: @Maniero,  A pergunta original não possuía a tag `php`. As tags originais eram `orientação-a-objetos` e `engenharia de software`. O editor achou por bem colocar `php` e a tirou do escopo. O pseudo-php foi o veículo que o usuário convencionou como adequado para veicular sua duvida como se fosse um algorítimo.

Comment: @AugustoVasques eu vi, na verdade só agora vi que elas mudaram :) Minha resposta complementar, na maior parte, foi em cima de nem ser PHP (só um trecho falo nisto)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim essa passagem de parâmetro que você está fazendo é sim uma passagem de parâmetro por referência e os resultados obtidos respeitam os paradigmas da POO.

> **Quanto as suas perguntas:**

**Isso seria um comportamento padrão da orientação a objetos?**

Sim esse é o comportamento é padrão para POO. O que prejudicou a compreensão, ao meu ver, foi a escolha dos nomes da classe e das instancias.

**Existe uma maneira correta de fazer o envio desses objetos sem alterar os atributos do objeto original?**

Sim existe uma maneira correta de fazer o envio desses objetos sem alterar os atributos do objeto. O que aconteceu no caso foi que a linguagem executou exatamente o que você ordenou que fizesse.

---

> **Reinterpretação do exemplo:**

Para facilitar a compreensão vou fazer algumas modificação nos exemplos que você deu.

```
//   Mudei o nome da classe Teste para classe Exemplo pois a repetição da  
//palavra teste em diferentes contextos estava confusa.
    class Exemplo 
    {
        private $atributo;

        public function getAtributo(){
            return $this->$atributo;
        }

        public function  setAtributo($valor){
            $this->$atributo = $valor;
        }

        //   Aqui fiz outra modificação troquei o nome do parâmetro de $teste
        //para $alvo. Só para simplificar.
        public function incrementar($alvo){
            $alvo->atributo += 1; 
        }
    }
```

O primeiro exemplo eu dividi em quatro situações, que as enumerei de 1.1 até 1.4, e ao invés de uma instância da classe exemplo usei duas instâncias.

> **SITUAÇÃO 1.1**

Crio duas instancias de `Exemplo`, `$objeto1` e `$objeto2`. Inicio o atributo de `$objeto1` com `0` e inicio o atributo de `$objeto2` com `10`. Usei esses valores para que os resultados fiquem distintos.

Nesse exemplo eu faço `$objeto1` incrementar o atributo de `$objeto2`:

```
$objeto1 = new Exemplo();
$objeto2 = new Exemplo();
    $objeto1 ->atributo = 0;
    $objeto2 ->atributo = 10;
    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
        $objeto1 ->incrementar($objeto2);
    }
```

Resultados:

```
$i = 0 => $objeto1 ->atributo = 0 ; $objeto2 ->atributo = 11
$i = 1 => $objeto1 ->atributo = 0 ; $objeto2 ->atributo = 12
$i = 2 => $objeto1 ->atributo = 0 ; $objeto2 ->atributo = 13
```

---

> **SITUAÇÃO 1.2**

Nesse exemplo eu faço `$objeto1` incrementar o atributo do próprio `$objeto1`, tal qual o exemplo 1 na pergunta:

```
$objeto1 = new Exemplo();
$objeto2 = new Exemplo();
    $objeto1 ->atributo = 0;
    $objeto2 ->atributo = 10;
    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
        $objeto1 ->incrementar($objeto1);
    }
```

Resultados:

```
$i = 0 => $objeto1 ->atributo = 1 ; $objeto2 ->atributo = 10
$i = 1 => $objeto1 ->atributo = 2 ; $objeto2 ->atributo = 10
$i = 2 => $objeto1 ->atributo = 3 ; $objeto2 ->atributo = 10
```

---

> **SITUAÇÃO 1.3**

Nesse exemplo eu faço `$objeto2` incrementar o atributo de `$objeto1`:

```
$objeto1 = new Exemplo();
$objeto2 = new Exemplo();
    $objeto1 ->atributo = 0;
    $objeto2 ->atributo = 10;
    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
        $objeto2 ->incrementar($objeto1);
    }
```

Resultados:

```
$i = 0 => $objeto1 ->atributo = 1 ; $objeto2 ->atributo = 10
$i = 1 => $objeto1 ->atributo = 2 ; $objeto2 ->atributo = 10
$i = 2 => $objeto1 ->atributo = 3 ; $objeto2 ->atributo = 10
```

---

> **SITUAÇÃO 1.4**

```
$objeto1 = new Exemplo();
$objeto2 = new Exemplo();
    $objeto1 ->atributo = 0;
    $objeto2 ->atributo = 10;
    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
        $objeto2 ->incrementar($objeto2);
    }
```

Resultados:

```
$i = 0 => $objeto1 ->atributo = 0 ; $objeto2 ->atributo = 11
$i = 1 => $objeto1 ->atributo = 0 ; $objeto2 ->atributo = 12
$i = 2 => $objeto1 ->atributo = 0 ; $objeto2 ->atributo = 13
```

---

> **O que pode ser extraído desses exemplos?**

Desses exemplos pode-se extrair que o método é o instrumento pelo qual uma classe permite que suas instâncias realizem uma ação sobre um parâmetro.

Então se você passa a própria instância como parâmetro a ser consumido por um de seus próprios métodos, a instancia vira alvo de sua própria ação. Eg: cachorro tentando morder a própria calda. Situação 1.2 e situação 1.4.

---

> **SITUAÇÃO 2 e SITUAÇÃO 3**

Para uma perfeita visualização do comportamento POO, vou fazer uma modificação na classe `Exemplo`.

```
    class Exemplo 
    {
        private $atributo;

        public function getAtributo(){
            return $this->$atributo;
        }

        public function  setAtributo($valor){
            $this->$atributo = $valor;
        }

        public function incrementar($alvo){
            $alvo->atributo += 1; 
        }

        // Método que engloba o exemplo 2
        public function auto_incrementar(){
            $this->atributo = 0;
            for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
               $teste->incrementar($this); 
            } 
        }

        // Método que engloba ao exemplo 3
        public function incrementar_clone(){
            $this->atributo = 0;
            for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
               $teste->incrementar(clone $this);
            } 
        }

    }
```

Desta vez vou criar apenas um objeto(instância) da classe 'Exemplo' e vou chamar os métodos `auto_incrementar()` e `incrementar_clone()`

```
$objeto1 = new Exemplo();
$objeto1 ->atributo = 10;

$objeto1 ->auto_incrementar(); //Note que ates de chamar o método setei o atributo com 10
```

Resultado:

```
$i = 0 => $objeto1 ->atributo = 1 
$i = 1 => $objeto1 ->atributo = 2 
$i = 2 => $objeto1 ->atributo = 3
```

Por que isso?

Isso porque o método:

```
public function auto_incrementar(){
                $this->atributo = 0;
                for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
                   $teste->incrementar($this); 
                } 
            }
```

Equivale a:

```
public function auto_incrementar(){
                $this->atributo = 0;
                $this->incrementar($this); 
                } 
            }
```

Ou seja recai na situação ilustrada em 1.2 e 1.4.

Já a terceira situação do exemplo:

```
    $objeto1 = new Exemplo();
    $objeto1 ->atributo = 10;

    $objeto1 ->incrementar_clone();
```

Resultado:

```
$i = 0 => $objeto1 ->atributo = 0 
$i = 1 => $objeto1 ->atributo = 0 
$i = 2 => $objeto1 ->atributo = 0
```

Já que o método:

```
public function incrementar_clone(){
                $this->atributo = 0; // O atributo passou de 10 para 0
                for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
                   $teste->incrementar(clone $this);
                } 
            }
```

Equivale a:

```
public function auto_incrementar(){
                    $this->atributo = 0
                    $this->incrementar(clone $this); 
                    } 
                }
```

Porém se inspecionarmos os valores do `clone $this`. Para isso vamos assumir de forma grosseira que `$objeto2 = clone $this`. Recaindo sobre a situação 1.1 e 1.3

```
$i = 0 => $objeto2 ->atributo = 1 
$i = 1 => $objeto2 ->atributo = 2 
$i = 2 => $objeto2 ->atributo = 3
```

Comment: Ajudou bastante! Deu pra compreender que o erro é totalmente meu em relação a conceito e aplicação dos usos de POO. Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Vou responder só como complemento na parte que eu acho que a outra resposta está equivocada e porque a pergunta diretamente pergunta sobre isso. Não vou repetir o que concordo da resposta do Augusto, que é o grosso dela e que explica de forma correta o que é mais central na pergunta.

Tudo isso nada tem a ver com OOP. Então não é comportamento normal de OOP. Orientação a objeto é organização de código, por isso o que estes mecanismos fazem pouco importa para OOP. Um dos maiores perigos de uso de OOP é que quase ninguém entende sequer o que isso significa, então como fazer certo se o básico não é compreendido? Para fazer errado OOP não tem vantagem. E um detalhe importante é que OOP em PHP é errado por definição, PHP é uma linguagem de *script* e OOP é para problemas complexos com estado complexo, o que não existe em *script*.

Especificamente sobre o problema apresentado tem a ver com o comportamento do `clone` e nada com OOP.

A classe não faz sentido algum. Nem vou falar que [usa termo atributo incorretamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101). Ou que [deveria ter um construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101), ou que [abuse de *getter* e *setter*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101), ou mesmo que isto não deveria ser uma classe. Já tem tantos erros que por si só é um exemplo ruim, e se for só para mostrar o equivoco da passagem de parâmetro não precisaria tudo isso, mas não posso deixar de mencionar que o fato disto nem ser uma classe clara faz parte do problema. Se usasse o mecanismo do jeito certo não teria este problema.

Mas o erro conceitual grave é passar o próprio objeto criado como parâmetro para o método. Você está passando como parâmetro algo que já está sendo passado implicitamente (todo método é assim), então tem zero sentido em fazer isso, e aí começa ter problemas por uso equivocado do mecanismo. Este método `incrementar()` não deveria existir desta forma, simples assim.

Faria algum sentido se a função fosse estática. Não muito para este caso, mas não seria tão absurdamente errada. Ainda seria estranho passar uma instância desta própria classe.

Os exemplos da outra resposta que começam ser um pouco mais OOP fazem todo sentido, mas faz uma coisa bem diferente do que foi proposto pelo AP.

Reforço que se não houvesse o erro conceitual não haveria o erro no mecanismo.

Não acho que os nomes ruins, e são ruins, foram determinantes para compreensão errada do que ocorreu. Todos nomes e conceitos estão errados nesse exemplo.

Comment: Você está coberto de razão.