# Qual a diferença entre o método construtor e a utilização do setters em orientação a objetos em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, construtor

A pergunta pode parecer meio tosca, mas fiquei com dúvidas e gostaria de compreender mais a fundo.

O construtor ele alimenta os objetos criados da classe, correto?

As dúvidas são:

1. Então qual seria a utilidade dele se tem os *setters* que alimenta também o objeto?
2. Posso trabalhar com uma classe em JS apenas com o construtor sem os *getters/setters* ou trabalhar sem o construtor ficando com os *getters/setters*?
3. De algum modo da dúvida 2 isso irá atrapalhar em algo quando for realizar herança?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre o construtor já foi respondido em: [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

Em geral é um erro trabalhar só com *getters/setters* justamente pelo que está escrito no *link* acima, mas pra tudo existe exceção. É muito comum trabalhar sem *setters* porque muitos objetos devem ser imutáveis. Há casos que se trabalha sem is *getters* também por duas razões:

- essa ideia de *getter/setter* é considerada errada por muita gente que prega que deveria ter método que tem um comportamento mais específico e que por acaso alterará o estado do objeto, mas que não deve ter métodos cuja única função seja alterar o estado de um membro sem mais nada fazer
- em muitos casos criar *getter/setter* não traz vantagens e é melhor usar o membro direto (em JS sempre fizeram isso, mas está espalhando uma ideia de usar isto em outras linguagens que não são Java, onde começaram usar isso efusivamente, eu considero um erro o uso indiscriminado). As pessoas usam esse padrão sem entender porque ele existe e que problema ele resolve e se resolve de fato o que pretende, as pessoas assim que existe essa regra e deve ser usada sem questionar. Quem sabe programar só os usa em casos onde eles são úteis.

Pode ver mais sobre isso em [diversas perguntas aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101).

O último item a resposta é não.

Comment: Pesquisei a respeito também, e vi sua resposta, e ao meu entender pelo que percebi, vai de acordo com a necessidade então.
No Java por exemplo, aprendi a declarar 2 construtores, um vazio e outro para preencher. Para caso precisar instanciar um ou outro e não ter problemas.
Já no PHP que estou estudando agora, só há como declarar um, então quando for instanciar um objeto eu serei obrigado a passar os parâmetros via construtor, então não achei muito interessante seu uso. Óbvio que vai depender da necessidade.

Comment: O construtor vazio junto com um outro em grande parte das vezes é um erro. Acho que sua visão de construtor está completamente equivocada.