# Como setar variável de instância usando o valor lido de um Scanner?

Tags: java, classes

Como declarar o valor de uma variável de instância da classe `Paciente` pela classe `Main` com o `Scanner` em Java?

Códigos:

```
public class Paciente{

  private double cod;
  private String nome;

  public getNome(){
      return this.nome;
  }

  public void setNome(String NomedoPaciente){
      this.nome = NomedoPaciente;
  }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Sacanne(System.in);
        Paciente p01 = new Paciente();

        System.out.printlm("Digite o nome do Paciente: ");
        String nomedopaciente = input.nextLine();
        p01.setNome(nomedoPaciente);
    }
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Este código tem uma quantidade enorme de erros de digitação (e des organização que não impede a compilação) e isso é o que está impedindo funcionar, mas eu resolvi responder (ainda que possa ser inócuo) porque o código tem vários erros conceituais.

Quase todas classes deveria ter um [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) que faça sentido e inicialize um objeto em um estado válido.

Quase sempre o uso de *getters* são desnecessários ou inadequados e deveria dar preferência para métodos que façam algo mais significativo e *setters* fazem menos sentido ainda porque em geral boa parte dos dados não deveria ser mudados, mas se puderem ser então deveria ser por um método que tenha mais semântica. Sem falar que em muitos casos acessar o campo direto seria mais simples e fácil, é só saber o que está fazendo. Entenda mais o assunto seguindo *links* em [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101).

Precisaria criar um mecanismo  para controlar os código que eu troquei para inteiro porque não faz o menor sentido ter um `double`.

Programar orientado a objeto é modelar os objetos de forma correta, com os conceitos certos, caso contrário não precisa dessa complexidade.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite o nome do Paciente: ");
        Paciente p01 = new Paciente(1, input.nextLine());
    }
}

class Paciente {
    private int codigo;
    private String nome;
    public Paciente(int codigo, String nome) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getNome() { return nome; }
    public void setNome(String nome) { nome = this.nome; }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jZ0HpI). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ConstructorSet). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/ConstructorSet.java).

Comment: muito obrigado, me perdoe pelo erros estou estudando programaçao desde janeiro deste ano e comecei no zero mesmo entao ainda tenho dificuldades pq estva sem internet, tudo q sei foi atravez de livros e apostilas mas nada melhor que alguem com experiencia pra no levantar e ajudar, sou humildemente grato irmao...