# Não consigo aceder à função

Tags: php, array, funções

Estou a tentar aceder à função `getTitleIdLocation()` de modo a aparecer os valores que dei às três variáveis, mas não consigo. Não posso chamar o *array* desta maneira?

Código:

```
<?php

class Imovel {

private $title;
private $id;
private $location;


 function __construct($title, $id, $location){
     $this->title = $title;
     $this->id = $id;
     $this->location = $location;
 }

 function getTitleIdLocation(){
     return $this->array($title, $id, $location);


 }
}

$casa = new Imovel ("Apartamento", "3", "Porto");
echo $casa -> getTitleIdLocation();
?>
```

Comment: Qual é o retorno que gostaria em `getTitleIdLocation`? O que deveria ser `$this->array`?

Comment: Gostaria que a função getTitleIdLocation imprimisse os valores de title, id e location.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, isso nada tem a ver com a função, tem com o retorno dela ou mais precisamente com a forma como está manipulando esse retorno. Você pode fazer isso, mas também deve tratar o retorno da função de forma adequada. Se recebeu um *array* deve imprimir cada elemento dele individualmente como qualquer *array*, você está tentando imprimir o *array* como um todo, então ele só mostra que é um *array*, se quer que cada elemento deve imprimir através de um laço, algo assim:

```
foreach($casa->getTitleIdLocation() as $item) {
    echo $item;
}
```

De qualquer forma tem um erro de chamada da função `array()`. Como está chamando ela com `$this`, o PHP acha que essa função pertence ao seu objeto, o que não é o caso, então tire isso. Pode até ser seja esse o que mais está preocupado, mas não é o maior erro, é só o mais visível.

Ou então você não quer resultar um *array*, quem sabe quer um dado em texto, algo assim:

```
function getTitleIdLocation(){
     return $title . " " . $id . " " . $location;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Array/Scan.php).

Mas pode ser que nem isso seja adequado, porque isso traz a informação formatada de um jeito que pode não ser o ideal para seu caso e será tentador até manipular esse texto para formatar de outra forma, ou seja uma gambiarra para consertar o conceito errado.

Ou pode ser que só queira retornar os itens individualmente e usar do jeito que bem entender. Aí a maioria das pessoas hoje em dia iriam criar um método chamado *getter* para cada membro da classe. É uma possibilidade, mas [isso é questionado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101) por alguns porque uma classe não deveria ter métodos com função específica definida ou outros dirão que o acesso ao membro diretamente não é tão grave quanto algumas pessoas dizem que é (sim, as pessoas seguem receitas de bolo sem questionar porque estão fazendo aquilo). Especialmente em PHP isso não faz muito sentido, mas as pessoas usam porque alguém leu um livro de Java e começou divulgar que em PHP tinha que ser igual. Boa parte dos programadores PHP adotaram isso sem questionar se fazia sentido, não vou dizer porque já que as pessoas ficam bravas quando conto o real motivo.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! O meu objetivo é mesmo imprimir todos os elementos do array tal como voçe disse. Coloquei o foreach para imprimir um elemento de cada vez, mas mesmo assim nao funcionou.

Comment: Aí você tem algum outro problema em um código novo, então tem que fazer outra pergunta, está dúvida eu respondi.

Comment: Quem negativou poderia dizer o que tem de errado pra eu consertar, odeio manter resposta errada. Caso não tenha essa informação provavelmente é só um voto de retaliação.

Comment: Só para deixar claro ... não foi eu! deve ser alguém que não entendeu o problema ou achou algo em sua resposta que não ficou claro (como citou retaliação, não tenho esse aspecto porque opiniões diferentes pelo motivo do fechamento, não credita a fazer isso na resposta que está certa)

Comment: @VirgilioNovic é bem estranho, porque esta pergunta claramente tem um problema em que ele chama uma função do PHP como se fosse do objeto e eu falo que isso é um problema e depois ele manda imprimir o *array*, quando ele quer imprimir os elementos, eu até especulei algumas opções. Já esta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/400513/101 recebeu 2 positivos em algo que nem deveria poder postar porque estava fechada, e ele especula o que ele quer fazer, o que se fosse o caso a pergunta seria fora de escopo porque querer que escreva todo o tópico,mas ela não é clara porque o erro ñ foi descrito

Comment: O erro é este:  `Coloquei o foreach para imprimir um elemento de cada vez, mas mesmo assim nao funcionou.`, só não está dizendo qual é o erro real, e lá também não está por isso não pode ser respondido adequadamente. Então a votação está bem esquisita.

Comment: Infelizmente sim o voto é estranho .