# clonar, copiar, objeto mutável no getter por segurança

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, segurança

Em muitos artigos e livros é citado que por segurança o correto é sempre entregar via getter uma cópia de atributos mutáveis.

Podendo ser um clone ou uma nova instância contendo os mesmos valores do teu atributo.

Já pesquisei bastante, e ainda não consegui entender aonde é que entra o perigo de entregar o próprio atributo mesmo que ele seja mutável.

No meu caso, minha aplicação usa um framework mvc para web, expondo uma api rest, acessando base de dados usando um ORM, os models e objetos de domínio possuem atributos mutáveis.

Aonde há risco de segurança?

Quando expomos uma biblioteca, api, dll, jar, ejb, vejo que sim, há problemas de segurança, por exemplo, se projeto uma condição no qual o cliente aplica um investimento numa determinada data e retira depois em outra, faço todo o cálculo baseado nas datas, a data por ser mutável, pode haver uma brecha, e o cliente (um outro sistema, um parceiro, um terceiro) propositalmente pode alterar a data antes de imputar, mas não consigo ver em outros cenários.

Infelizmente até mesmo aplicativos formidáveis como o Sonar Qube possuem regras para barrar códigos que exponham objetos mutáveis.

Comment: encontrei outro possível motivo, dependendo da natureza do teu sistema e da complexidade envolvida, poda acontecer de um código teu alterar uma data por exemplo que lá na frente não deveria, visto que a data está totalmente exposta, você não tem controle e pode gerar alguma inconsistência, isso na prática não consegui imaginar, mas estruturalmente é possível.

Comment: encontrei algumas explicações no site do SonarQube: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2384 e no site Common Weakness Enumeration: http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/374 mas não me foi convincente, a explicação limita-se a própria aplicação, ou seja, um código dentro da própria aplicação pode alterar o valor antes de executar outro método, não consigo ver real perigo.

Answer (score 2):

Isso nada tem a ver com segurança, nem de uma forma, nem de outra, segurança é outra coisa. O que podem estar falando é que evita-se algum problemas fazer assim, então seria seguro  por causa disto, mas não tem a ver com o conceito de segurança que costumamos falar. Então se viu em algum lugar sobre código mal intencionado explorar algo por causa da forma como você organiza o código jogue está coisa fora agora. Então para responder o que quer saber, isso não faz sentido, não encontrada nada porque isso não existe.

Há muita confusão do que se fala sobre orientação a objeto porque tem escolas diferentes sobre o assunto e cada uma prega uma coisa diferente, o que já dá pra ver que não deveria ter tanto valor quanto as pessoas dão para isto.

Um exemplo de conceito errado é que atributo até é usado em orientação a objeto conceitual, mas não faz sentido chamar de atributo nas linguagens, porque quase todas chama isso de [campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

O use de *getter* é questionável, tem inúmeras perguntas sobre o assunto aqui, pode começar por [Métodos Getters e Setters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101).

O que se fala é que você escondendo o campo atrás de um método *getter* te dá mais flexibilidade e esconde o detalhe de implementação, então se um dia precisa mudar algo ali fica mais fácil porque tem uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101), só isso. E não é limitado a campos mutáveis.

A questão de clonar também parece esquisita, teria que ver o contexto, em geral não se deve clonar objetos complexos. Perguntado assim o que está falando não faz sentido, pode fazer em algum cenário específico.

Como falou de *frameworks* pode ser que algum exija isto por uma motivação interna, mas teria que ver o contexto.

Portanto a pergunta parte de muitas premissas erradas, o caminho do seu aprendizado está todo errado e mistura coisas que não tem relação alguma. Minha sugestão é procurar outra fonte de consulta ou mudar o método de aprendizado.

Fazer algo errado pode ter haver com segurança, mas não porque algo é mutável ou imutável ou porque tem *getter*, ou porque clona algo. Talvez seja porque algum componente desses deixa algo externo mexer em algo interno no código, bom aí a tecnologia usada é insegura e deveria ser descartada, não é um problema de orientação a objetos ou da linguagem.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, mas não é a respeito de getters em si que pergunto e sim sobre entregar objetos mutáveis. Estudei mais um pouco e cheguei a conclusão que numa biblioteca, api, ou mesmo num ejb eu corro riscos ao expor um objeto mutável, risco de segurança, veja que um consumidor, maliciosamente pode alterar uma data crucial num investimento por exemplo, sendo que eu projetei para aquela data ser apenas de leitura. Vou melhorar minha pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Em OO existe a preocupação de não violar o encapsulamento das classes, ou melhor, a ocultação das informações. Podemos dizer que é um princípio de design.

Essa violação ocorre por exemplo quando a classe tem um campo na forma de uma coleção (por exemplo, uma lista) de itens e você expõe essa coleção através de um getter.

Existe o perigo de manipular a coleção obtida dessa forma e alterar o estado interno do objeto indevidamente. O ideal seria ter passado uma cópia da coleção, que se for feita de itens imutáveis tanto melhor (se não forem, que sejam pelo menos cópias dos itens originais).

Dessa forma você preserva a coleção original e pode manipular à vontade a versão copiada (ou não, se tiver passado uma coleção somente-leitura).

É uma forma de segurança, do ponto de vista dos clientes dessa classe (pensando nos clientes de uma biblioteca de classes por exemplo), que não podem ingenuamente ou maliciosamente alterar o estado interno dos objetos dessa biblioteca.

Se precisar forneço um exemplo.

Comment: seria de grandíssima valia exemplos, pois atualmente não consigo ver muitos riscos, 99% das aplicações não expoem mais uma api via dll, ejb, jar, ou seja o que for para um terceiro, mas sim apenas web services ou end-points rests. Ainda mais com a adoção de microserviços, não há mais essa interação no mesmo host. Mas mesmo para outros cenários me seria de gradíssima valia.

Comment: O perigo é em interações no mesmo host, como no caso de uma aplicação desktop ou backend usando uma biblioteca ou outra forma de código-servidor. Mas não sei se consigo idealizar um exemplo prático dessa situação. Quando propus ilustrar com um exemplo, estava pensando na mecânica da coisa, retornar um `Collections.unmodifiableList()` do Java em vez da lista em si, usar objetos imutáveis na lista retornada, esse tipo de coisa. Não seria um exemplo muito aplicável.

Comment: Sim @danilo você está correto, e minha resposta e a do Piovezan confirmam isso, o problema não é de segurança, é só de organização de código e tem tudo a ver com *getters*. Note que ele fala de violação de princípio e não quebra de segurança. O que eu não gosto muito, embora *eeu** entenda a frase, é falar sobre perigo, porque as pessoas podem achar que é perigoso sofrer um ataque ou algo assim e na verdade é só perigoso o programador cometer um erro. Ataques podem ocorrer por outros motivos, não por esse. É só sobre o risco de cometer um erro e não de ser atacado.