# Por que as variáveis de instância normalmente são inicializadas no construtor?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, variáveis, engenharia-de-software, construtor, inicialização

Eu já vi diversos códigos onde as variáveis de instância de uma classe são inicializados no construtor, até eu mesmo faço isso por ver os outros fazerem. Porém eu nunca entendi isso.

Lógico que tem as variáveis de instância nas quais tem o valor definido baseado no argumento dado nos parâmetros do construtor, mas eu vejo na maioria das vezes variáveis de instância sendo inicializados com objetos dentro do construtor.

Um exemplo (pseudocódigo):

```
class Exemplo {
    var obj;

    construtor() {
        obj = new Objeto();
    }
}
```

Existe algum motivo para isso? Ou só virou um "costume" mesmo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro, você está usando uma nomenclatura errada, mas não é culpa sua, quase todo mundo usa errado, veja em [Qual a diferença entre atributo e campo, nas classes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

O exemplo é péssimo porque ele é errado, mesmo que fosse correto daria problema porque entraria em *loop* infinito.

Veja [não funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/YMwMTH). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hbQ5XU). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/ConstructorLoop.cs). Vale para qualquer linguagem.

Acho que assim é o que deseja fazer:

```
class Exemplo {
    var obj;
    Exemplo() {
        obj = new Objeto();
    }
}
```

Uma classe ou definição de tipo parecido com uma classe tem duas partes: uma é a estrutura de dados que é praticamente um metadado que indicará como será a estrutura do objeto, que campos formarão este objeto físico; e outra que são os métodos, que nada mais são que funções que operarão em cima dessa estrutura.

Apenas as funções possuem algoritmos, os campos sequer existem durante a execução, eles servem só para orientar o que acesso, é só uma forma para facilitar a codificação de acesso à memória. Qualquer operação a ser executada precisa estar em uma função/método. Então quando você quer criar um objeto na memória é uma operação a ser executada e precisa estar dentro de um método, e este método pode ser o construtor.

Quando você diz `obj = new Objeto()` está chamando o construtor de `Objeto`, que é um método e está criando um objeto na memória, o `new` indica que haverá uma alocação ali, e este objeto (provavelmente uma referência a ele) será atribuída para o campo `obj` da sua classe.

Se você não fizer isso o que aconteceria em uma linguagem que deixa livre fazer como quiser? O campo não seria inicializado e teria um valor qualquer de acordo com o que já estava na memória naquele momento.

Algumas linguagens fazem o zeramento da memória neste momento, mas ela faz em um construtor mesmo que não pareça que tem um a linguagem cria para você.

Algumas linguagens deixam você inicializar o campo diretamente nele, mas na verdade é só *syntax sugar*, no fundo está criando um construtor e a inicialização está sendo colocada lá. Assim:

```
class Exemplo {
    var obj = new Objeto();;
}
```

vira:

```
class Exemplo {
    var obj;
    Exemplo() {
        obj = new Objeto();
    }
}
```

E no momento que mandar criar um objeto `Exemplo` este construtor será chamado e executará este código. No fim na estrutura de dados não pode conter algoritmo, então mesmo que veja uma execução em um código de estrutura de dados na verdade ele será reescrito para jogar no construtor sem você saber.

Então se você só quer que o campo seja inicializado com um valor padrão e isto não precisa ser configurado não tem porque depender de parâmetro, você só inicializa o valor desejado.

Existe um motivo para isto, sempre que o código foi escrito por alguém que sabe o que está fazendo. E é só um costume se a pessoa aprendeu com receita de bolo e não tem ideia do que está fazendo e mesmo assim se julga programador.

Faz-se isto se há necessidade para resolver o problema desta forma, se o que deseja é um objeto com um valor específico sempre que inicia um objeto novo deste tipo, mesmo que depois esse valor possa ser trocado dentro de um método que faça essa alteração (algumas pessoas criam um método *setter* para isto, e [quase sempre não é o ideal a fazer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101)). Se não tem necessidade não usa assim. Sempre é a necessidade que deve determinar o que fazer e não uma regra mágica universal.