# Instanciar uma entidade dentro de outra entidade: como fazer?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, instanciar-objeto, dependências

A classe `Estado` depende da classe `Pais`. Qual seria a diferença entre eu fazer isso:

[image: Código]

E fazer isso?

[image: Código]

Ou seja, qual a diferença de eu instanciar a classe `Pais` dentro da classe `Estado` para instanciar a classe `Pais` numa classe principal para depois eu atribuir o `Pais` ao `Estado`?

Comment: Seria interessante colocar o código formatado na questão ao invés de imagens.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 2):

Ao contrário do que diz a outra resposta não é questão de performance, a não ser que esteja falando da qualidade deste código em específico. A questão é de garantia de construção. Leia [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

Agora deve estar pensando: mas isso não é um construtor, como esta pergunta aqui pode ser sobre isto?

Acontece que isto que está fazendo na verdade é colocado em um construtor. Mesmo que você não criou um ele será criado pelo compilador para colocar o código que inicializa o objeto. Até porque [a estrutura de dados não executa nada, tudo é executado em métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/420762/101) e o construtor é um método. Você não está vendo mas a inicialização de verdade está em um método construtor. A única mágica é essa mudança de lugar do código feito pelo compilador. A JVM não faz mágica alguma, não inicializa de forma mais rápida ou diferente.

A única vantagem é que sempre que o objeto for criado é garantido que esse valor já estará lá no objeto antes da JVM dar controle para seu código consumidor. Só lembrando que neste caso `pais` receberá um ponteiro apenas depois de executar o construtor `Pais()` e obter o endereço desse outro objeto que estará em outra área da memória - possivelmente logo sem seguida. Não faz diferença se essa alocação é feita dentro da classe (no construtor ou outro lugar) ou em outro método externo à classe, a não ser que o local de alocação **pode** ser ligeiramente diferente porque a ordem de alocação **pode** ser diferente no caso de inicializar em outra classe.

Não lembro em Java se a a construção nesta forma garante alguma ordem, eu acredito, por isso não tome como verdade absoluta, que as inicializações ocorrem na ordem que foram declaradas na classe, mas sem garantias. Certamente essas inicializações ocorreriam antes de outras feitas explicitamente dentro do construtor criado por você (será o mesmo construtor, é só questão da ordem que o compilador coloca).

Sem colocar na classe você está deixando livre que este objeto seja criado sem um valor naquele campo.

O uso de *getter* e principalmente *setter* costuma ser usado de forma equivocada em quase todos códigos, especialmente por novatos que aprendem a receita de bolo e não a motivação deles existirem (e quase sempre não deveriam existir). [Tem *links* onde isto é mostrado e até discutido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101). Por exemplo, um `Estado` poderá trocar de `Pais`? Quando ele é criado, ele poderia ficar um tempo sem um `Pais()`? Por que?

Por outro lado esse código tem outro problema na criação do `Pais()`. Que país está sendo criado? Um país nulo, sem informação? Estranho, será que em outra situação é entra em estado válido? É mais grave dentro da classe, porque se é criado um objeto inválido ali possivelmente poderá ficar inválido sempre, pelo menos se o código for feito com o uso do construtor e o padrão de modificadores de estado de forma correta, o que este código não o fez. Porque esses dados devem ser mutáveis?

Na forma atual do código não tem sentido algum criar aquele objeto na classe. Ele está inicializando o campo `pais` com objeto inválido (pra que?) e que deveria ser inicializado depois então. E depois em `main()` está inicializando de forma inválida por um tempo, por sorte o programador, acredito eu, construiu o objeto aparentemente correto antes de armazená-lo no `estado`. Se o código deixa e até induz fazer coisas erradas ele está todo errado, mesmo que funcione.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Se considerar que está alocando dois objetos completamente diferentes (um na classe e outro em `main()`, um deles tornando o outro desnecessário e abandonado logo em seguida, aí pode, neste código específico que está errado, ter um pequeno custo extra de performance porque criar um objeto a mais tem um custo e põe pressão no *garbage collector* que terá que lidar com esse objeto criado na inicialização da classe que de fato nunca foi usado.

A lógica de criação de `ids` aí pede para dar problema, não deveria deixar na mão do programador cuidar disso.