# Em Java, getter e setter abstrato é correto?

Tags: java, herança, polimorfismo, classes-abstratas, método-abstrato

Eu tenho uma classe pai abstrata `Usuario`. E uma classe filha `Usuario_Adulto`.

O atributo `idade` está na classe abstrata `Usuario`. Para validá-lo fiz um método *setter* abstrato na classe pai, pois o atributo é `protected`, mas e se fosse `private`? Como poderia validá-lo na classe filha?

Está certo fazer isso?

Comment: Leia a resposta do Maniero abaixo e repense se precisa mesmo de uma subclasse para distinguir adultos de não-adultos. Talvez baste um método `ehAdulto` ou similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenho medo desse tipo de herança, só não afirmo que ela está errada porque não tenho informações suficientes. Até pode estar certo, mas só poderia afirmar entendendo cada detalhe. Programar, especialmente orientado a objeto, é entender cada detalhe. Por alguma razão algumas pessoas acham que isso não é necessário.

Aproveito para dizer que [o que chama de atributo na verdade é correto chamar de campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Também quero dizer que [as pessoas abusam e usam errado *setters* e *getters*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101).

Se tiver um motivo para qualquer um dos dois ser abstrato então eles devem ser mesmo. O fato de ser abstrato pode ajudar a herança ser um pouco mais certa, ainda não garanto, mas se `Usuario` não pode ser instanciada é um indício de algo bom.

O que deseja? Se quer a implementação seja dada apenas na classe concreta então parece que é só fazer isso.

Se você quer só chamar na classe `Usuario` um método que ainda é abstrato para fazer alguma validação, pode fazer isso sem problemas, todo esse mecanismo foi criado para ser assim mesmo. Quem chamar não precisa saber como está sendo feito lá dentro, não precisa nem saber que lá dentro na própria classe não tem implementação, ele só precisa chamar algo que ele sabe que existe, que é o contrato do método. Obviamente que só funcionará quando implementar o método em uma classe herdada, o que é a única forma de instanciar esse tipo.

E de fato se o método for acessar um campo da classe mãe e a implementação da classe concreta precisa poder acessar o campo lá na classe mãe e então ele não pode ser `private`, teria que ser `protected`.

Ao mesmo tempo pode não ser a forma certa. Pode estar violando a abstração. Talvez o que precise não é um método abstrato. Pode ser que queira um método implementado na classe mãe que acessa o campo privado, e aí na classe filha você reimplementa o método fazendo o que quer e chamando em determinado momento o método da classe mãe quando for acessar o estado que está em um campo da classe mãe.

Algo assim:

```
@Override
public void setA(int value) {
    if (value > 0) super.setA(value);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/SetterInherited.java).